# SvelteKit + Supabase OAuth Redirect Issue

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I'm currently learning SvelteKit and Supabase + Supabase authentication. I'm using Google OAuth for user login, [following the tutorial from here](https://supabase.com/docs/learn/auth-deep-dive/auth-google-oauth). When a user logs in with the Google provider, I successfully receive a redirect URL like this: `https:<xxx>.supabase.co/auth/v1/authorize?provider=google&code_challenge=<xxxx>&code_challenge_method=s256`.

However, when the user is redirected back to the homepage the session is null. The session is only populated after I manually refresh the page.

Here's how I'm handling the google log in:

```js
  login: async ({ request, locals, url }) => {
    const provider = url.searchParams.get("provider") as Provider;

    // If there's no provider or it's not supported, return a 400
    if (!provider || !supportedProviders.includes(provider)) {
      return fail(400, {
        error: `Provider either does not exist or is not supported."`,
      });
    }

    // Sign in with the provider
    const { data, error: err } = await locals.supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: provider,
    });

    if (err) {
      return fail(500, {
        error: err.message,
      });
    }

    // We did it! Redirect the user to the URL provided by the provider
    throw redirect(303, data.url);
  },
```

Here's the code for my +page.server.ts `load` function:

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ url, locals: { getSession } }) => {
  const session = await getSession(); // This is null after redirect, but is populated on refresh

  if (session) {
    throw redirect(303, "/account");
  }

  return { url: url.origin };
};
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to the timing of when the session is established. How can I ensure that the session is properly populated after the initial redirect without requiring a manual page refresh?

Comment: Please take a look at this tutorial how to correctly sign in with OAuth when using the auth-helpers https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/oauth-with-pkce-flow-for-ssr, you are missing a redirect URL and an endpoint to handle the exchange code for session.